# Install Android TV app on mobile Android

Tags: applications, android-tv

I have a Wetek Play 2 Android media player. It has "normal"/mobile Android 6 as operating system. I would like to be able to install Android TV apps (the OS in some smart tv). However they are not visible for me in Google play store. Is there a safe way to get Android TV apps for mobile Android?

**Edit:**
As an answer to @beeshyams (who says it is not possible to install TV apps on a mobile device):
The alternate app market Aptiode has a TV version called [Aptiode TV](http://blog.aptoide.com/how-to-install-aptoidetv-2/). From their web page it says:

> Aptoide TV brings you an app store that offers content with a rich
>   user experience, optimized for the larger screen devices, such as
>   high-definition televisions. Yep, it means that **you can use Aptoide
>   not only in your mobile devices**, but also in the comfort of your
>   couch.

I have tried installing two apps from that store and I could start them but they crashed when I tried to view some streaming contents. Probably because the versions of the apps supplied by *Aptoide TV* were outdated.

So I think that it is possible to install Android TV apps on a mobile version of Android. (I understand that they are not *intended* for mobile.)

Comment: Are you asking for how you can see Android TV apps in Google Play as opposed to just side load them? Is the device rooted?

Comment: From what I have read Aptiode TV is simply an alternative store app that can install Android apps that are optimized for TV screen. Those apps are still regular Android apps, not Android TV apps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Android TV - Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_TV)
 says

> (it )  [is a **Smart TV**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_TV)
>   Platform

(Emphasis Supplied)

*Android TV app is meant for Android TV* - Which to me means it cannot run on mobile . To support :

- You can't find it on Play Store because it is not meant to be installed on mobile devices
- *Other Devices* section of Wiki quoted, doesn't mention mobile / media players of regular Android
- Net search doesn't reveal the possibility

Bottom line - You can't

---

**Edit:** Post your revision

1. The extract from the blog you linked gives you the impression that you can install TV apps on your mobile but to my understanding that's not the case. It explains you can download the app on your mobile and use your mobile as a play store for TV apps but doesn't claim you can *install and run on your mobile*
2. If you visit [Aptoide](http://en.aptoide.com/) , which is an alternative play store, you will see a bunch of apps *Aptoide TV*. Only one of them has an app description that reads

> .... The optimised app store for your set top box and Smart TV

3. [Install Apps On Your Android TV From Your Smartphone With AptoideTV](http://blog.aptoide.com/remote-tv-install/) claims that you can install mobile apps on your TV

Lacking practical experience and based on these, my conclusion is that you can't install TV apps on your mobile (and that's probably why those you tried to install crashed).

Requesting readers to clarify based on their experience. Thanks

Comment: please see my update. I believe I can install TV apps on a mobile device.